# programming Arduino in c++ on the pi

Tags: arduino, c++

I'm new to the Pi and linux in general, what I'm trying to do is program an Arduino in c++ with the Arduino IDE. A sketch in the Arduino language works fine, but the equivelent code in C++ uploads but does nothing even though the same code uploads fine on a windows machine

```
//works fine on windows, not on linux
    using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  while(1)
  {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 254; i++)
    {
      Serial.println(i);enter code here
    }
  }
}

//works fine on linux
    void loop()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void setup()
{
   for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 254; i++)enter code here
    {
      Serial.println(i);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use a uint8_t in your for loop. Use an int. The for loop seems gratuitous anyway. Don't import the entire std namespace, only the bits you need. The arduino make system generates a C++ source file from your sketch, so ditch main.

Comment: You seem to be missing code. Without the whole program I'm afraid there's little we can do here.

Answer (score 1):

That code looks markedly different to all the Arduino sketches I have seen which have at least two functions.

1. setup()
2. loop()

They do no contain a main().